# RecyclerView resets custom view's LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to insert a list of custom views into a recycler view, but for some reason, the recyclerview resets the layoutparams of the custom views. I found that it works if I maunally set the layout params in the custom views constructor.

MainActivty.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(layout.activity_main)
        findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler).apply {
            adapter = ArticleSectionsAdapter()
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

view_online_video.xml

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:parentTag="com.example.layouttest.OnlineVideoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="24dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/video_placeholder"
        />
</merge>
```

ListAdapter.kt and BaseViewHolder

```
class ArticleSectionsAdapter :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder>() {

    private val list:List<String> = listOf("","","")

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(OnlineVideoView(parent.context))
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(view: OnlineVideoView) : BaseViewHolder(view)

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder, position: Int){ }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size
}


open class BaseViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
```

OnlineVideoView.kt:

```
class OnlineVideoView : ConstraintLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)


    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.view_online_video, this)

        // THIS CODE MAKES IT WORK, BUT WHY??
        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )

        setPadding(24)
    }
}
```

video_placeholder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
    <size android:width="256dp" android:height="144dp"/>
</shape>
```

This is what it looks like. From the example code I omitted some code that handles different layouts. But that works fine, and gets inflated correctly.

*If I manually put in the layout params in the OnlineVideoViews contructor, it WORKS, but I don't think thats a viable solution as Im basically writing duplicate code.*

[image: Bug]

Comment: You're ending up with two `ConstraintLayout`s in each of your custom `View`s: the one from the `<ConstraintLayout>` in the internal layout, and the `OnlineVideoView` itself. That is, you're inflating a second `ConstraintLayout` into your custom `ConstraintLayout`. You would want to use `<merge>` tags as the root in the internal layout, not another `<ConstraintLayout>`. I should also mention that if the only thing inside each custom `View` is an `ImageView`, then having an outer `ViewGroup` wrapping it is rather pointless, and your IDE might be giving you a warning saying as much.

Comment: I tried <merge> already. And I checked the layout inspector, and there's only one contraintlayout in the hierachy :/ And there's actually more views inside, but I removed them for this demostration (and I also tested without them, and it still didn't work)

Comment: I forgot to mention that this would also depend on how exactly you're creating and initializing the `OnlineVideoView`s in the `Adapter`, but that part is missing in the given example.

Comment: Hi I cleaned the example inside a new project, and the error is still there. The code above is now 100% reproducable

Comment: OK, I think this boils down to a simple misunderstanding of how `LayoutParams` work and how they're applied to `View`s. To begin, any attribute that starts with `layout_` will be passed to the _parent_ to create `LayoutParams` for that child. For example, in your `activity_main`, that `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf` attribute on the `<RecyclerView>` is actually handled by the `ConstraintLayout`, because `layout_*`s and `LayoutParams` are info for the parent on how the lay out the child. Secondly, `View`s do not have `LayoutParams` by default, because they depend on which type the parent is.

Comment: And the last point here is that `<merge>` tags don't really take any attributes; they're meant to act like they're not really there at all, so its attributes are ignored. So, in your setup, `OnlineVideoView` is being created directly, without layout XML, so it has no `LayoutParams` generated and it gets `RecyclerView`'s defaults, which wraps in both directions. Your `layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(...` in the `init` block is effectively substituting for what `LayoutInflater` would have done if you had inflated your custom `View` from a layout with...

Comment: ...`<OnlineVideoView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">`. For better organization, you could move that block into `onCreateViewHolder()` instead, but it needs to be done somewhere, either in a layout or in your code. Make sense?

Comment: Ok, so its a combination of a) <merge> not accepting any layoutparams and b) View Class not having any inherent layoutparamt. But futherly, the custom view does not apply the layoutParams from the XML even if specified via parentTag, correct? (Because it breaks even if I replace the <merge> with <ConstraintLayout> with layoutParams)

Comment: Wait, so why didn't it work when I used <ConstraintLayout> instead of <merge>? The CostraintLayout had layout_width=match_parent and SHOULD apply them inside its parent, which is also a <ConstraintLayout> with layout_width=match_parent

Comment: Sounds like you got it. Yeah, the original setup is a bit different, and I didn't want to confuse the situations. In that case, the `layout_*` attributes _were_ being applied, but to a separate `ConstraintLayout` inside your `OnlineVideoView` (which itself is a `ConstraintLayout`). I think that was the original confusion, too. Even though your custom `View` is a `ConstraintLayout` subclass, that has nothing to do with what is in its internal layout. Everything inside that layout is created like normal, so you get a `ConstraintLayout` added to your `OnlineVideoView`, and that...

Comment: ...`ConstraintLayout`'s attributes have no effect on your `OnlineVideoView`, just like the `ImageView`'s attributes have no effect on its parent. Imagine if you changed that `<ConstraintLayout>` to a `<FrameLayout>`. You wouldn't expect that `FrameLayout`'s attributes to apply to your `OnlineVideoView`, would you?

Comment: I see yeah. Well I would expect that when I when I inflate any layout, that its attributes and layout params are carried over, no?

Comment: Carried over to what, exactly? As mentioned, when you had the `<ConstraintLayout>`, those attributes _were_ being applied, but to that `ConstraintLayout` _inside_ your `OnlineVideoView`. However, your `OnlineVideoView` has no `LayoutParams`, so `RecyclerView` sets defaults, and `OnlineVideoView` is wrapping the inner `ConstraintLayout`. That hierarchy is ending up `OnlineVideoView` -> `ConstraintLayout` -> `ImageView`, and the `ConstraintLayout` in the middle is completely redundant. With the `<merge>` tags, it would be just `OnlineVideoView` -> `ImageView`, which seems to be what's expected.

Comment: Yeah so maybe its just my personal opinion/understanding, but inflate() is a class method of View, so I would *hope* that when when I call inflate on *any* layout-xml with layoutparams defined that it would *use* those layoutparams! I would maybe understand if I had called addView(), because then I assume that there's a view inside my custom view. But calling *inflate*, I would assume I replace the custom view's layout, more or less.

Comment: No problem. The `View.inflate()` method is just a static helper that calls `LayoutInflater#inflate()` underneath. Nothing is being replaced or removed anywhere. Your `OnlineVideoView` is simply acting like a specialized container for other `View`s.